# Create routes in google maps v3 but avoiding markers

Tags: google-maps

I would like to create a new route with an origin and finish, but I wish that the route would avoid going through certain points I have marked and google maps offer an alternate route.

Where I can find this?

Excuse me for my unfortunate english :/

Thanks.

pd: i want the follow: if google maps returns a route with de streets A B C D E and I have a marker in a street C, I want one route avoid marker C and google maps returns alternate route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You can find alternate routes, though, using the `alternatives` option.

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to do this with Google's API.

Their routing algorithm runs a shortest path (i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithm on a graph data structure that represents the road network. In order to exclude a particular road segment, you'd need to set the weight of that segment to a very high value so that the algorithm wouldn't use it in the path.

There isn't any way to tell Google's routing algorithm to use a client defined weight for a given road segment. You'd have to alter the server-side graph structure and I doubt Google will let you do that.